# Dump the body of a function or procedure in sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

How can I dump out the body of a function or a procedure when using sqlplus to connect to an oracle database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select
    text
from
    user_source
where
    type = 'PROCEDURE'
and
    name='YOURPROCEDURENAME'
order by
    line;
```

Comment: Likewise type='FUNCTION' and name='YOURFUNCTIONNAME'.

Comment: We have several different schema set up.  Do I to do anything special to deal with those?

Comment: You can either log into the specific schema, and user_source will only contain that schema's source.  Or you can log in as a DBA and the dba_source table will also have an owner column which you can include in your where clause to specify which schema you are interested in.

Comment: Actually, you want "select text". The LINE column has the line number.

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
SELECT us.name,
       us.type,
       us.text
  FROM USER_SOURCE us
 WHERE us.type IN ('PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION')
ORDER BY name, line
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use the ***dbms_metadata*** api

```
set line 200
set long 10000
select dbms_metadata.ddl('PACKAGE','Package Name') from dual;
```

You can use this for all metadata including ***tables, indexes and constraints***.

Comment: Upvoting because those 'set line/set long' will be needed for the other mechanisms as well I think.

Comment: @monojohnny, `set long` is not needed for *the other mechanisms*. Still +1, as dbms_metadata *is* the way to go, imho.